# Tensorflow: why is there a diffrence in training a model and params directly

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Below is a simple program I wrote. Its job is to learn the parameters of a simple linear function Ax+B.

When training "manually" it converges after a few thousand epochs, but when I try to do the same using a Dense(1) layer+model it converges to a loss of 500000, and the trained parameters are nowhere near the correct ones (-2, 34).

I thought Dense(1) layer is just like Ax+B, but it's not?

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import numpy as np


x_train = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
y_train = -2*x_train+34


def manual_train():
    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-2)
    vars = [tf.Variable(random.random(), trainable=True) for i in range(2)]
    for epoch in range(1000000):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = vars[0]*x_train + vars[1]
            loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y_train - y_pred))
            model_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, vars)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(model_gradients, vars))
            print(epoch, 'parameters', vars[0].numpy(), vars[1].numpy(), 'loss', loss.numpy())


def nn_train():
    input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(1,))
    output_layer = layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomUniform(0,1), bias_initializer=initializers.RandomUniform(0,1))(input_layer)
    model = models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-2)
    #model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=None)
    for epoch in range(1000000):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = model(x_train.reshape((-1,1)))
            loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y_train - y_pred))
            model_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(model_gradients, model.trainable_variables))
            print(epoch, 'parameters', model.trainable_variables[0].numpy(), model.trainable_variables[1].numpy(), 'loss', loss.numpy())


# uncomment one:
manual_train()
#nn_train()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem of shape in your keras example.

Because of that problem, the operation `y_train - y_pred` does not exactly what you think it does.
Because at that point, y_train has a shape of `(100)` and `y_pred` a shape of `(100,1)`, when you do the subtraction, TensorFlow will do a "smart" [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), and the end result is an array of size `(100,100)`

Reshape your ground truth to the same shape as your output (or the other way around), to get the correct value of your loss:

```
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y_train.reshape((-1,1)) - y_pred))
```

Comment: That was it - thanks! For future generations please fix a typo in your brackers - reshape((-1,1))